# VUEJS V-FOR acting weird

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

I need a simple v-for to render object properties in a list.

```
<div
   v-if="profileData && profileData.length > 0"
>
  <ul
    v-for="value in profileData"
    :key="value.id"
  >
    <li>{{value.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the script:

```
profileData: {},
created() { 
  const userId = this.$route.params.userId
  const currentUser = this.$store.getters.currentUser
  const profileData = this.$store.getters.profileData 
  console.log('profileData in seeProfile: ', profileData) }
```

(profileData comes from an api response)

I did exactly the same in two other pages (just rendering different objects) and it worked.
With this code, in the console I get `value is undefined`.
If I remove `:key="value.id"` (it becomes red in the editor but it still works), and instead of the list items I type only `{{ value }}}`, then the object properties get rendered ( but in the ugly format of a js object). How can it be? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: `profileData` is not an array, so you are looping through its object values.

Comment: Got it. So? Should I bind the values instead of the keys?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It's up to that. I would debug it with first printing the object `{{ profileData }}`. Then, you can see the structure. If it is an array, you can loop through the items with `<li v-for="item in profileData">{{ item }}</li>`. You can then see the single items in `<li>` elements. If you want to loop through an object, you can do it like this: `<li v-for="(itemValue, itemKey) in profileData">{{ itemKey }}: {{ itemValue }}</li>`. If this works, you need to bind a unique key to the `<li>` element to make it more performing.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Console log returns a list of properties, profileData is indeed an object, so what I need is looping through its properties. I've already tried what you suggested, but it doesn't work. It's weird, I don't know where to look at....

Comment: `console.log` might print a different object than the one you are looping through in the template - depending on when you print it to the console. Adding it to the template should present you always the current one. E.g. when a watcher changes this object and you did not expect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api has been changed, so the working code is slightly different from the original one.
Here's the template:

```
<div
  v-if="listData.length"
>
  <ul>
    <li>Name: <b>{{ profileData.user.first_name }}</b></li>
    <li>Surname: <b>{{ profileData.user.last_name }}</b></li>
    <li>Username: <b>{{ profileData.user.username }}</b></li>
    <li>Car: <b>{{ profileData.if_cars_owned }}</b></li>
    <li v-if="profileData.if_cars_owned === true">
      Car model: {{ profileData.user_car_type }}
    </li> 
    <li v-if="profileData.if_cars_owned === true">
      Car power: {{ profileData.user_car_powered_by }}
    </li> 
    <li>Motorcycle: <b>{{ profileData.if_motorcycle_owned }}</b></li>
    <li v-if="profileData.if_motorcycle_owned === true">
      Motorcycle model: {{ profileData.user_motorcycle_characteristic }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
created(){
    const profileData = this.$store.getters.profileData
    this.profileData = profileData
    console.log('profile data in profilo: ', profileData)
  },
```

I've also updated

```
<div
  v-if="listData.length"
>
```

and in the script

```
computed: {
    ...,
    listData() {
      let list = Object.values(this.profileData);
      return list;
    }
},
```

following the advice of @Adrián S. Basave.
Thanks to anyone who tried to help.
x

Answer (score 1):

Your v-if will never show even if `profileData` has data, because you can't directly check for the length of an Object in javascript.

A few things:

1. You can't check for the length of an Object, it will return `undefined`. If you must use an object, then you'd have to check for `Object.keys(obj).length`.

```js
let obj = {
  first: {
    name: "first",
    meta: "data"
  },
  second: {
    name: "second",
    meta: "data"
  }
};

console.log("Object.length is: ", obj.length);
console.log("Object.keys().length is: ", Object.keys(obj).length);
```

2. You're being redundant, you don't need to check for `profileData` and its length (and you don't need to > 0), you could simply check for `v-if="Object.keys(profileData).length"`. If the Object has zero entries, then it won't show because `if(0)` is false.
3. I'd strongly recommend to work with arrays to iterate with v-for. I'd use computed properties and return an array, and iterate through that. Object reactivity works non-intuitively in JS, so you'll be scratching your head later when you try to find out why stuff isn't updating on your view:

```
computed: {
    listData() {
        let list = Object.values(this.profileData);
        return list;
    }
}
```

In view:

```
<div v-if="listData.length"/>
```

Also, don't use the array's entry index as your `:key`, because if you have another array with `v-for`, you'll have duplicated keys in your model. I'd use something like `v-for="(item, key) in list" :key="'list-item-' + key"`

Answer (score 0):

Put the `v-for` on the `li`, not the `ul`.

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="value in profileData"
    :key="value.id">{{value.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Also , if your your profileData is an object and not an array, you need to decide if you want to loop through the keys or values.

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="value in Object.values(profileData)"
    :key="value.id">{{value.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="value in Object.keys(profileData)"
    :key="value.id">{{value.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Or use Vue's default behavior.

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="(value,key) in profileData"
    :key="value.id">{{value.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is correct, but it won't address the problem noted in the comment, so nothing will display. (`profileData.length` will be `undefined` since `profileData` is an object.)

Comment: @Steven I put the v-for in the li, as you suggested, and removed the v-if directive as pointed out by Stephen, but still the values are not rendering. No errors in the console though.

Comment: Why do you use `Object.values`? This is unnecessary and you even need a polyfill for this in IE. See the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object

Comment: As stated in the link you provided: "v-for with an Object
You can also use v-for to iterate through the properties of an object.
```
<ul id="v-for-object" class="demo">
  <li v-for="value in object">
    {{ value }}
  </li>
</ul>``` I did so, it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like your object is not what you expect it to be at the time of the loop ‍♂️ Print it in template to see if the object looks like it should.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I use `Object.values` to make it clear what you get instead of relying on the `default` that is awkward considering for-in will return something different than for-of.  No doubt earlier JS implementations before ES6 made some terrible decisions.

Comment: `v-for` in a vue.js template behaves differently than `for..in` as it always returns the value of the property (as the first argument, the key as an optional 2nd and the index as an optional 3rd). This is specific to Vue.js and properly described in the docs as the only way to directly loop through an object in a template. But you can of course first map it to an array and then loop through that.

Comment: That is true, Vue does loop through objects differently than JS.  Even more the case why casting as I did makes the code clearer.  You still do have access to the index as a second argument.  Anyway, here is a link to the docs you referenced.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object.  I updated solution with this syntax.

Comment: So, just writing ```<div>
              <ul>
                <li>{{profileData}}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>``` shows {} on the template. So I guess the template is accessing the profileData object before it gets filled by the api. How to make sure it does only when all data have been loaded? I read about watchers and life cycle hooks but I am not sure on how to use them in the code.

Comment: In my code I only have ```created() {
    const userId = this.$route.params.userId
    const currentUser = this.$store.getters.currentUser
    this.currentUser = currentUser
    console.log('STORE IN SEE PROFILE: ', this.$store.state)
    console.log('currentUser in seeProfile: ', currentUser)
    const profileData = this.$store.getters.profileData  
    console.log('profileData in seeProfile: ', profileData)
  }```

Comment: For your first question, you use `v-if/v-else`: `<div v-if='! profileData'>Loading...</div><div v-else>{{profileData}}</div>`

Comment: Please update your question with your component's data section and created method.